# Как перенести артикли каждый в свой PDF?

Tags: excel, pdf, generate

У меня есть 200+ артиклей, они хранятся в exel таблице. Мне нужно их взять и перенести каждый артикл в каждый отдельный PDF файл. В итоге должно быть столько же PDF сколько и артиклей, и каждый со своим артиклем. Как из exel взять и перенести так можно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можно увидеть ваши попытки решения и образец данных?

Comment: >> *Как из exel взять и перенести так можно?* Можно. Написать макрос, который пробежит по таблице, соберет один артикул, создаст PDF, соберет другой, создаст... Если совсем нет знаний в этой области, обращайтесь на фриланс-биржи, писать такое с нуля - это выходит за рамки простой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

У рабочего листа есть свойство "Область печати", которым и нужно воспользоваться. Перебираете свои артиклы в цикле, устанавливаете область печати на нужные ячейки/строки, печатаете лист в PDF.

Подсказки хватит, или нужен код? Вот здесь

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76792483/convert-invoice-page-excel-to-pdf-using-vba/76792666#76792666

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76730756/exporting-excel-ranges-on-different-tabs-as-a-pdf-in-vba/76730951#76730951

есть нужные куски кода.